# date of birth - day filter depending on month

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I am currently working on a day dropdown list for date of birth,  the values in this field will depend on what month is selected.  I currently have this working as shown below but I want to move the logic into the controller or a filter and not leave it in the html file.

```
 <select  name="personal_dob_day" ng-model="dob_day">                 
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                <option>19</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>21</option>
                <option>22</option>
                <option>23</option>
                <option>24</option>
                <option>25</option>
                <option>26</option>
                <option>27</option>
                <option>28</option>
                <option ng-if=" dob_month != 'February' || !( dob_year % 4)")>
                    29
                </option>
                <option ng-if=" dob_month != 'February'">
                    30
                </option>
                <option ng-if=" dob_month == 'January' || dob_month == 'March' || dob_month == 'May' || dob_month == 'July' || dob_month == 'August' || dob_month == 'October' || dob_month == 'December'">
                    31
                </option>
 </select>
```

What I want to do is in the controller create an array as such:

```
   var dayRange = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=31;i++) {
      dayRange.push(i);
    }
    $scope.days = dayRange;
```

and use ng-options to loop through like this:

```
<select  ng-options="day for day in days track by day" name="personal_dob_day" ng-model="dob_day" >
```

I am thinking if I do it this way is it possible to implement a filter of some sort which would check the values of the month model and only display the appropriate days in the dropdown for days? If so how would I go about creating such a filter as my experience with them is limited. Or perhaps there is a better way all together to go about this?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider using the ng-options directive passing in an expression that pulls the labels from an array in the model of the controller.

First construct the controller that will hold the arrays for the Years, Months and Days. Create properties on the $scope object so you can access those arrays through the ng-options directive on the view.

If you include JQuery as a dependency you can construct your arrays the following way:

```
var years = $.map($(Array(numberOfYears)), function (val, i) { return i + 1900; });
var months = $.map($(Array(12)), function (val, i) { return i + 1; });
var days = $.map($(Array(31)), function (val, i) { return i + 1; });
```

If you prefer not to have a JQuery dependency just use a good old for loop for all three arrays. The following code will give you accessors on the $scope for the arrays:

```
$scope.Years = years;
$scope.Months = months;
$scope.Days = days;
```

Back in your HTML view add a select element with the ng-options and ng-model ng-options directives for example:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="BirthdayController">
<select ng-model="SelectedYear" ng-options="label for label in Years"></select> 
<select ng-model="SelectedMonth" ng-options="label for label in Months"></select> 
<select ng-model="SelectedDays" ng-options="label for label in Days"></select>
</div>
```

I am assuming you are familiar with creating AngularJS modules and adding controllers to it as well as adding the necessary ng-app directive, ng-scope class and ng-controller directives to the containers. Up to this point you will have three drop down lists containing a list of years, a list of 12 months and a list of 31 days respectively. If you want to have a dependent day list keep reading! :)

Refer to this plnkr for the basic version: http://plnkr.co/edit/VfEpwPv084H7XiifEsnm?p=preview

**Bonus round:**

You can take this one step further and make the days list show correct number of days since days really has a dependency on the month and year selected. February has 28 days on non leap years and 29 days on leap years. Other months have 30 or 31 days depending on the month. If you want to go all fancy you need a function in the controller to determine leap years and to determine how many days to return to calculate whether a year is a leap year in javascript the following function is quite useful:

```
var isLeapYear = function (selectedYear) {
var year = SelectedYear || 0;
return ((year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0)) ? 1 : 0;}
```

Although it will look slightly different using Angular since the $scope will already contain the selectedYear and won't have to be passed in. The isLeapYear helper function is accessed by another function which determines how many days to display for the given month and year combination as follows:

```
var getNumberOfDaysInMonth = function (selectedMonth) {
var selectedMonth = selectedMonth || 0;
return 31 - ((selectedMonth === 2) ? (3 - isLeapYear()) : ((selectedMonth - 1) % 7 % 2));}
```

Now all that needs to be done on the original select element for days would be to add a limitTo filter on the ng-options directive to change how many elements are actually rendered. The Select element for Months and Years require a ng-Change directive so we can update the field on the $scope which will hold the number to limit the days by.

```
<select ng-model="SelectedYear" ng-options="label for label in Years" ng-change="UpdateNumberOfDays()"></select> 
<select ng-model="SelectedMonth" ng-options="label for label in Months" ng-change="UpdateNumberOfDays()"></select> 
<select ng-model="SelectedDays" ng-options="label for label in Days | limitTo:NumberOfDays"></select>
```

Where NumberOfDays is populated in the function on the controller $scope.UpdateNumberOfDays() which of course will utilize the helper function GetNumberOfDaysInMonth described above.

And as an extra bonus here is a plnkr for the smart version: http://plnkr.co/edit/AENh6Ynj4kNKZfLsXx4N?p=preview

Enjoy!

Comment: to void display bank option in ng-options, you should set value to $scope.SelectedYear = 1, $scope.SelectedMonth=1, $scope.SelectedDays=2016

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}</option>
</select>
```